# Live ASP Search Insert into List

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, search, asp-classic

There are two questions I have with this latest project:

A user will select an option from a drop down.  Depending on that selection, I need to run a query to pull all documents associated with that selection.  These are the documents that the user will then be able to search through.

Then I need to build a live search option that updates after every couple characters entered by the user.  Once the user finds the correct file, they are able to select it and have it populate into a list below.

I am pretty stumped here and could use some guidance or link references.  ASP is not a very familiar language for me but I've been tasked to build this in ASP regardless.

Comment: Are you doing classic asp or asp.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a mixture of cascading drop downs, javascript and ajax for classic asp.

Ajax in classic asp is not easy but you should be able to accomplish this.

[Classic asp ajax](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/39/AJAX-and-Classic-ASP)

Although cascading drop downs is not exactly what you need, it will show you how to invoke an element using a drop down. If you mix the cascading drop down with Ajax it should get you there.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax not necessary.
I've done this using just Javascript and ASP.
Here is some code from a project I did awhile back:
http://www.oceanmedia.net/fin_examples.zip
in the code you will see every piece that you need :-)